# How to serialize Model @property with ModelSerializer?

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm trying to serialize a model containing a property field that I also want to serialize.

models.py:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.AutoSlugField(populate_from='name')

    @property
    def ext_link(self):
        return "/".join([settings.EXT_BASE_URL, self.slug])
```

serializers.py:

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('name', 'ext_link')
```

When trying to get to the related URL, I'm getting a serializer exception (KeyError) on the `ext_link` property.

How can I serialize the `ext_link` property?

Answer (score 178, accepted):

Because it's not a model field, it needs to be added explicitly to the serializer class

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ext_link = serializers.Field()

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('name', 'ext_link')
```

Comment: ***One note***: The fields list in Meta is optional. If you omit `fields`, in the above example, you would get all the `MyModel` fields plus `ext_link` in the serialized data. And this is really awesome for complex models! *EDIT*: At least, this is true for `djangorestframework==2.3.14`.

Comment: For me, using serializers.Field gave an error. "serializers.ReadOnlyField" does work if to_representation is not defined and the view is read-only.

Comment: I'm using 3.3.x and simply adding properties to fields is not sufficient. I still have to explicitly add via ext_link = serializers.ReadOnlyField().

Comment: using DRF 3.4.6 on Python 3.5.1 and Django 1.10, adding to fields works fine.

Comment: Note: Using `fields = "__all__"` I also had to add `myfield = serializers.ReadOnlyField()` as jarmod specified, using version 3.7.7

Comment: In addition: if using Swagger for your API documentation, it makes sense to specify the field not as `serializers.ReadOnlyField()` but explicitly as the type the @property is returning like `hasLink = serializers.BooleanField(read_only=True)`. Otherwise Swagger will always refer to it as a `string`.

Comment: > Creating a ModelSerializer without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute has been deprecated since 3.3.0, and is now disallowed.

Answer (score 61):

as `@Robert Townley`'s comment, this work with version `3.8.2`:

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ext_link = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = "__all__"
```

Answer (score 13):

The accepted answer doesn't seem to work for me, nor does the `ReadOnlyField`.

However, I have had success when I use a field that corresponds to the return type of my property function.

So for the example, I would do this:

```py
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ext_link = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('name', 'ext_link')
```

I've been able to do this with `ListField`, `DictField`, and `IntegerField` as well.

Comment: best answer!!!!

Comment: [serializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) also might help

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it is what worked for me as well. The accepted answer did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you might want to do is add a property that its contents are not a string. Let's say you have a model called Person and another one called Food that look like this (we assume that each food is the favorite of only one person, making it a `OneToMany` connection):

```py
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    @property
    def favorite_foods(self):
        return Food.objects.filter(person=self.pk)

class Food(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    persons_favorite = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

If you want to add `favorite_foods` in `Person`'s serializer all you have to do is:

```py
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    favorite_foods = FoodSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('name', 'favorite_foods')
```