# Concatenate a specific field from child objects into parent object?

Tags: django, django-orm

I have two models:

```
class Chapter(models.Model):
    chapter = models.IntegerField()
    verses_amount = models.IntegerField()
    chapter_content = models.TextField()
    

class Verse(models.Model):
    chapter = models.ForeignKey(Chapter, on_delete=CASCADE)
    verse = models.TextField()
    verse_number = models.IntegerField()
```

On `Verse`, I store a paragraph in the `verse` field.
How can I query all children (`Verse`), get their `verse` paragraph, concatenate all those and put that in `Chapter.chapter_content`?

Eg

```
verses = Verse.objects.filter()[0:2]
for verse in verses:
    print(verse.verse)

>> 'Lorem Ipsum.'
>> 'Second Lorem Ipsum Iteration 2.'
```

In the parent `Chapter`, I want `chapter_content` to hold the two values as one long string:

'Lorem Ipsum. Second Lorem Ipsum Iteration 2.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```py
chapter = Chapter.objects.get(chapter=1)  # or whatever chapter you want to get

content = ""

for verse in chapter.verse_set.all():
   content += f"{verse.verse} "

content = content.rstrip()

chapter.chapter_content = content
chapter.save()
```

But it is bad practice to store the verse both in `Verse` objects as in `Chapter` objects, because what if you want to update just one verse?

You could try to make the `chapter_content` a method property in the `Chapter` model.

```py
class Chapter(models.Model):
    chapter = models.IntegerField()
    verses_amount = models.IntegerField()

    @property
    def chapter_content(self):
        content = ""
        for verse in self.verse_set.all():
            content += f"{verse.verse} "
        return content.rstrip()
    

class Verse(models.Model):
    chapter = models.ForeignKey(Chapter, on_delete=CASCADE)
    verse = models.TextField()
    verse_number = models.IntegerField()
```

Note that you still have to sort the verses by their order number.

Comment: I like the `property` approach - will it work with django rest as well? Can it be used in the serialized response?

Comment: Yes, it will. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066074/modelserializer-using-model-property

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238025/discussion-between-erikvm-and-wouter).